# dynamic import statement from an array

Tags: javascript, meteor, dynamic-programming, meteor-blaze

I'm building a meteor app, and I'd like to know if it's possible to do something along the lines of:

```
var pages = [
  'home',
  'contact',
  'other'
];

for(var page in pages){
  import `/path/${page}`;
}
```

It's a small thing, but It would make things much simpler when it scales up. The above code doesn't compile, because import doesn't allow for interpolation. I've looked into using require syntax, which compiles, but can't find the files if I use interpolation. I also tried using meteor's dynamic-imports package, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most (if not all) build engines do not support interpolated import paths. They perform a static analysis to determine loaded assets.

Even Meteor dynamic imports need static paths, the "dynamic" part is about when the loading actually takes place, but Meteor still needs to know the path in advance.